# É possível uma trigger Mysql inserir valores errados

Tags: c#, mysql

Tenho essa Sp que atualiza o estoque:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`comandas`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_AtualizaEstoque`( id_prod int, qtde_comprada int, preco_vend decimal(9,2))
BEGIN
    declare contador int(11);
    declare qtd_atual int(11);
    DECLARE qtd_estoque INT (4);


   SELECT count(*) into contador FROM estoque WHERE id_produto = id_prod;
    IF contador > 0 THEN

                    SELECT qtde INTO qtd_estoque FROM estoque WHERE id_produto = id_prod;
                    IF qtd_estoque >= (qtde_comprada*-1) THEN
                         UPDATE estoque SET qtde=qtde + qtde_comprada WHERE id_produto = id_prod;
                    ELSE 
                       If qtd_estoque>0 THEN
                        UPDATE estoque SET qtde=0 WHERE id_produto = id_prod;
                       END IF;

                    END IF;

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO estoque (id_produto, qtde, preco_venda) values (id_prod, qtde_comprada, preco_vend);
    END IF;
END
```

Tenho uma tabela chamada saida_produto dentro dela tem 3 trigger para acionar a Procedure acima

uma delas é essa que é acionada no after insert:

```
 CALL SP_AtualizaEstoque (new.id_produto, new.qtde * -1, new.preco_venda);
```

Até ai tudo bem. O que acontece quando estou fazendo os teste no ambiente de teste funciona perfeitamente, mas quando o sistema está sendo usado em rede em 4 computadores ao mesmo tempo, alguns produtos na tabela saida_produto é inserido com valores errados. 
Eu nunca vi acontecer isso, exemplo: eu comprei uma Coca com id 56, e na saída produto é registrado com id 34 que cai em outro produto. Dai o estoque fica todo bagunçado.
 Isso não acontece direto, acontece algumas vezes quando o sistema está altamente em uso no restaurante.
Eu uso o sistema em rede onde no servidor está instalado o Mysql, e o sistema foi programado C#.
Alguém me dá um socorro ou alguma sugestão?

Comment: E qual o `ISOLATION LEVEL`de sua transação? Provavelmente o `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` atende a suas necessidades.

Comment: esta como padrão o REPEATABLE READ. Vou tentar ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE, obrigado pela resposta.